# How jqxSwitchButton get value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I get and set jqxSwitchButton value?
I use this code to create a switch button,and want to get the Button value.But it did not work.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>SwitchButton</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style_edit.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jqwidgets/styles/jqx.classic.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jqwidgets/jqxswitchbutton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jqwidgets/jqxcheckbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#jqxSwitchButton').jqxSwitchButton({checked: true});
        // Get the value.
        var value = $("#jqxSwitchButton").jqxSwitchButton('val',true);
        var value2 = $("#jqxSwitchButton").val();
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value2);

        // Set value.
        $("#jqxSwitchButton").jqxSwitchButton('val', true);
        // Set value using jQuery's val().
        $("#jqxSwitchButton").val(true);

        });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="switch_options">
<div id="jqxSwitchButton" value="A"></div>
</div>
```

it return two Boolean "true",like the doc say:
Parameter   Type
value(optional) Boolean
Return Value
Boolean
How can I get the value "A"? 
means return String,then set the value.
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I use attr to get and set the value,
but don't know why .val() can not get the value

```
        $("#jqxSwitchButton").attr("value","N");
```